# Кто может помочь отхешкетить Keepass?

Tags: безопасность, криптография, взлом, password-hash

Ребят, забыл часть сложного пароля к базе данных Keepas 2. Кто может помочь с подбором пароля на Hashcat? Обладатели мощных видеокарт, откликнитесь, пожалуйста. Время на поиска - несколько минут. Основная часть пароля известна, надо найти оставшиеся символы. Хеш и маску для поиска отправлю в личку.

Comment: Вы перепутали сайт... Вам нужно на сайты фрилансеров.

Answer (score 1):

Вам прямиком на [форум Античат](https://forum.antichat.ru) - там много таких, которые на спор брутфорсят всевозможные хэши.

Comment: исправьте ссылку. в адресе отстуствует n